# jQuery extract form data returned by Ajax call

Tags: jquery

I am doing an Ajax call to a page, which returns HTML containing a form. I need to extract and serialize this form, to perform another Ajax call using this form data in POST. How to accomplish this with jQuery?

Here's the example code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  ...,
  success: function(data)
  {
     // "data" object contains HTML with a form
     // extract form data from "data" object
     // make another Ajax POST to another page, posting extracted form data
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: It would be probably easier if you told us what is the forms structure. Or is it possible it might differ on each call? And what do you want to send with POST for the second time exactly? Form is a structure you need to fill **with** data, not the `data` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  ...,
  success: function(data)
  {
      var formData = $(data).find("form").serialize();
      $.post("/another/url", formData, callback);
  },
  ...
});
```